# Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools - Solution Navigator Shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Love the Solution Navigator in VS2010 power tools. But can't find a shortcut combination that opens it?

Answer (score 0):

Looking in my keyboard mappings it was down as Ctrl w+ Ctrl F. This seemed to clash with the search functionality so I reassigned it.